# How to change the code to control the names of certain buttons?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

There is a code

```js
$("button").click(function() {
    var btn = this;
    if (btn.loaded) {
      $(btn).prev("div").html(btn.originalContent);
      btn.loaded = false;
      $(btn).text('Get Dynamic chart');
    } else {
      btn.originalContent = $(btn).prev("div").html();
      $(btn).prop('disabled', true);
      $.get($(btn).data("url"), function(html) {
        $(btn).prev("div").html(html);
        $(btn).prop('disabled', false).text('Close');
        btn.loaded = true;
      });
     }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">
  <h2>Dynamic chart1</h2>
</div>
<button data-url="https://stackoverflow.getsandbox.com:443/dashboard?a=1">Get Dynamic chart1</button>

<div id="div2">
  <h2>Dynamic chart2</h2>
</div>
<button data-url="https://stackoverflow.getsandbox.com:443/dashboard?a=2">Get Dynamic chart2</button>

<div id="div3">
  <h2>Dynamic chart3</h2>
</div>
<button data-url="https://stackoverflow.getsandbox.com:443/dashboard?a=3">Get Dynamic chart3</button>

<div id="div4">
  <h2>Dynamic chart4</h2>
</div>
<button data-url="https://stackoverflow.getsandbox.com:443/dashboard?a=4">Get Dynamic chart4</button>

<div id="div5">
  <h2>Dynamic chart5</h2>
</div>
<button data-url="https://stackoverflow.getsandbox.com:443/dashboard?a=5">Another button</button>
```

So, `Button 5` has a different name from everyone, but when you click on it, the name of the script changes to `"Close"`, this is normal. But after clicking the close button, the name of the button is assigned a script on the `Get Dynamic chart` instead of `"Another button"`, that is, the native name does not prevail. How to make sure that the `5th button` before pressing and after pressing are not assigned names by the script, or how to assign the `5th button` in the script its names for `opening`, `closing` and `returning to the original name`? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

But what's so unclear about it?

First time you click it, this runs:

```
   btn.originalContent = $(btn).prev("div").html();
      $(btn).prop('disabled', true);
      $.get($(btn).data("url"), function(html) {
        $(btn).prev("div").html(html);
        $(btn).prop('disabled', false).text('Close');
        btn.loaded = true;
      });
     }
```

So `btn.loaded=true`, and `text` is now "Close"

Next time you click, this runs:

```
  $(btn).prev("div").html(btn.originalContent);
  btn.loaded = false;
  $(btn).text('Get Dynamic chart');
```

It did exactly what you told it to do.

A better question is... What exactly do you MEAN for it to do?